# Unable to create a table & insert values in the database

Tags: database, vb.net, sqlite

The below code is suppose to create a database and  a table with a column "FirstName"  which is assigned a value "James"

```
Imports System.Data.SQLite
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("c:\mydatabasefile.db3")
        Dim sqlConnection As New SQLite.SQLiteConnection()
        Dim sqlCommand As New SQLiteCommand

        sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=c:\mydatabasefile.db3"
        sqlConnection.Open()
        sqlCommand.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE MyTable(EmpID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC,  FirstName VARCHAR(25));"
        sqlCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MyTable(FirstName) VALUES('James');"
        sqlConnection.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

But for some reason the app only creates a a database which has a size of 0 bytes. Why is it not working . I am using I am using SQLite ADO.NET Provider. , VS 2010, Winforms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are never executing the sql commands

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("c:\mydatabasefile.db3")
        Dim sqlConnection As New SQLite.SQLiteConnection()
        Dim sqlCommand As New SQLiteCommand("", sqlConnection)

        sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=c:\mydatabasefile.db3"
        sqlConnection.Open()
        sqlCommand.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE MyTable(EmpID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC,  FirstName VARCHAR(25));"
        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        sqlCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MyTable(FirstName) VALUES('James');"
        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        sqlConnection.Close()
    End Sub


End Class
```

You also need to be setting the Commands Connection which you can also do by saying

`sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection`
That should fix you up

Comment: oh, Can you tell me how to perform it , I am kind of new to this thing , trying to perform insert update and delete functions for the past 18 hrs

Comment: Look at my edits, I got the info from http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/docs/Devart.Data.SQLite~Devart.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.html

Comment: I am getting the error "No connection associated with this command ". VS highlights the 1st `sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Comment: You need to set the Commands connection, see my edits in about a minute

Comment: again getting an error, `'SQLiteConnection' is a type and cannot be used as an expression'`

Comment: typo it should just be SQLConnection :D

Answer (score 1):

You never execute the sqlCommands. You should use .ExecuteNonQuery() to get something into the database, otherwise nothing will be done.

Comment: So I have to call it for each single query ?

Comment: Yes. You do want each query to be executed, don't you?

Answer (score 1):

Also let the command know what connection to use.  sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection